# I'm getting this error ValueError: int is not allowed for map key while using Spacy and Msgpack

Tags: python, machine-learning, pip, jupyter-notebook, nlp

**I'm getting this error-
ValueError: int is not allowed for map key while executing the following code why this is happening ?**
Is this problem with version dependencies how to solve the problem?

pip:21.1.2
spacy:2.0.12
msgpack:0.6.2
msgpack-numpy:0.4.7.1
msgpack-python:0.5.6

```
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in from_bytes(bytes_data, setters, exclude)
    488 
    489 def from_bytes(bytes_data, setters, exclude):
--> 490     msg = msgpack.loads(bytes_data, raw=False)
    491     for key, setter in setters.items():
    492         if key not in exclude and key in msg:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\msgpack_numpy.py in unpackb(packed, **kwargs)
    271     object_hook = kwargs.get('object_hook')
    272     kwargs['object_hook'] = functools.partial(decode, chain=object_hook)
--> 273     return _unpackb(packed,**kwargs)
    274 
    275 load = unpack

msgpack\_unpacker.pyx in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb()

ValueError: int is not allowed for map key
```

Comment: v2.0.12 of spaCy is very old. If you can't use the latest v3, you should at least upgrade to 2.3.7, the most recent v2 release.